# Pandas apply lambda returning a tuple and insert into respective column

Tags: python, pandas

How can a pandas apply returning a tuple which the result going to be insert to the respective column?

```
def foo(n, m):
    a = n + 1
    b = m + 2
    return a, b

df['a'], df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['n'], x['m']), axis=1)
```

n and m in the lambda function is the columns to grab the value respectively. mean while i would like to return the result from foo and insert into the column a and b.

but the error message i get was "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

I can store the return tuple in a temporary column and split it but i was wondering if there is any way apply will be able to split the results into columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `result_type='expand'` to [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and assign to subset of columns in list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'n':[1,2], 'm':[5,6]})

def foo(n, m):
    a = n + 1
    b = m + 2
    return a, b

df[['a','b']] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['n'], x['m']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
print (df)
   n  m  a  b
0  1  5  2  7
1  2  6  3  8
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert tuple returned to Series

```
df[['a','b']] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(foo(x['n'], x['m'])), axis=1)
```